# Error events 50000780 in Event Log on Azure, what do they mean?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, event-log

In my Azure Web Site's Event Log I see same error every 1-5 minutes:

```
1 [varies]
5
50000780
```

[image]

What does this error message mean? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a [similar issue](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3d199ace-aca3-4845-b1ab-826e5c42bace/getting-the-simplest-sharepoint-lightswitch-htmlclient-apps-to-work-against-a-local-onpremise?forum=lightswitch), albeit for Sharepoint and Lightswitch. It looks like they had a similar error number show up in their event logs, breaking it down into the XML output:

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="IIS Express" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="32768">2284</EventID> <!-- Searched on this -->
    <Level>3</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-09-14T03:48:18.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>8608</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>PSN-W12S-720</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>1</Data>
    <Data>5</Data>
    <Binary>50000780</Binary>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Then I did a search on the EventID from above and found that there is an TechNet [Article about Event ID 2284](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc734951(v=ws.10).aspx) which essentially states that FREB wasn't able to write to the logs.

> FailedRequestTracing module failed to write buffered events to log
>   file for the request that matched failure definition. No logs will be
>   generated until this condition is corrected. The problem happened at
>   least %1 times in the last %2 minutes. The data is the error.

Do you happen to have Failed Request Tracing enabled for your site? If not you might want to, apparently it's trying to write something every 1-5 minutes.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much! New Relic was the reason of these events.

Comment: @AlexanderShvetsov I have the same Issue, even though FRT is enabled. Did you just remove New Relic or did you do something else?

Comment: Any update on what you did to fix this if it was a New Relic causing it.

Comment: +1 on any updates.  I'm not using NewRelic but my AppService is full of these.  I have FREB on, storing locally.